# Space of quintics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ that contain intersection of two quadric surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let the curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is an intersection of two quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3=\text{Proj}(S)$, $S=k[x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3]$. We have the following resolution of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_C$

$$0\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-4)\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-2)\oplus\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-2)\to\mathcal{I}_C\to0.$$

How to compute dimension of the space of surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree 5 that contain $C$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $H^1(\mathbb P^3, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(1))=0$, the sequence is exact on global sections when you twist by 5, so just calculate the dimension of $H^0\mathcal I_C(5)$ in the sequence
$$0\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P}(1) \to O_{\mathbb P}(3) \oplus O_{\mathbb P}(3) \to \mathcal I_C(5) \to 0.$$
If I have done the arithmetic correctly, this dimension is $40-4=36$, so conclude that the space of quintics containing this curve has dimension $35$.

Comment: Maybe you should add that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^n}(1)) = 0$.

Comment: OK, thanks. Done.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be correct.